# how to increase div height using javascript on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

could you please tell me how to increase div height using javascript on button click ?

I have two div's (one is yellow **background-color** and another is white **background-color**).

On button click I want to increase the height of `white` box. **but when I click on button it increase the height of yellow as well as white box ?**

why yellow div increase it's height when I click on button ..i want it height remain same after button click

here is my code

```js
function abc() {
  document.querySelector(".content").style.height = "300px";
}
```

```css
.abc {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, [row-start] 1fr);
  padding-top: 3.4em;
  padding-bottom: 3.4em;
}
.img {
  grid-column: col-start / span 8;
  grid-row: row-start / span 6;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 1074px;
  background-color: #ee0;
}
.content {
  grid-column: col-start 6 / span 6;
  grid-row: row-start 2 / span 6;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="abc">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="abc()">click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-lake-lw07u?file=/index.html:0-1282

Comment: Then you want the button to increase both or just white or yellow don't understand what you exactly want

Comment: I want only `white box` increase it's height not yellow one

Comment: The overall available height of the parent div increases when you increase the height of one div. Since the max-height is not set for the "yellow div" it will also expand. You can set max-height for the div to prevent it from expanding

Comment: max-height e.g https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-joana-9wspz?file=/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they're both being increased in height is because your `.abc` class doesn't have a set height. So when you increase the height of the content div you're also increasing the height of the parent, and therefore the Image div as well.

You can fix this by setting the height to the parent element

```
      .abc {
        ...
        height: 200px; 
      }
```